# Writing files to dynamic destinations in Parquet using Apache Beam Python SDK

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, parquet, pyarrow

I am trying to write Parquet files using [dynamic destinations](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.14.0/apache_beam.io.fileio.html#dynamic-destinations) via the `WriteToFiles` class.

I even found some further developed example like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62460186/7807920), where they build a custom Avro file sink.

I am currently trying to use the `pyarrow` library to write a Parquet sink that could manage the write operation in a distributed way, similarly to how it is done by the WriteToParquet PTransform.

```py
class ParquetFileSink(fileio.FileSink):
    def __init__(self, schema, codec='deflate'):
        self._schema = schema
        self._codec = codec
        self.writer = None

    def open(self, fh):
        # This is called on every new bundle.
        self.writer = pq.ParquetWriter(
            fh,
            self._schema,
            compression=self._codec,
            use_deprecated_int96_timestamps=False
        )

    def write(self, record):
        # This is called on every element.
        row = pa.Table.from_pandas(
            pd.DataFrame(record), schema=self._schema, preserve_index=False
        )
        self.writer.write_table(row)

    def flush(self):
        pass
```

The main issue here is that it is not possible, as far as I know, to write unbounded PCollections as Parquet files, so if I try to use the following class to write by record either I get an error for writing on closed file handlers, or some files are simply not created.
I also tried to write batches using a `GroupByKey` PTransform, however as it is not possible to close the `pyarrow.parquet.ParquetWriter` object, files end up written only partially and being corrupted. Moreover this strategy is not safe as batches could be very large and to write them as a single file is not a good idea.

I can see that this problem is being faced in the class [`apache_beam.io.parquetio._ParquetSink`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/cb52848db64f226d9b47b1c11eeb7b548af18e09/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/parquetio.py#L486), but I don't think this can be directly applied to the `WriteToFiles` class as I can't see how to fully manage file handlers with it.

Comment: It appears you are trying to do an "append" operation.  It's a great question and I recommend you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56747062/how-to-use-pyarrow-to-achieve-stream-writing-effect

Unfortunately, the verdict is that you cannot do this kind of append.  The normal operation is to write new files every so often and occasionally compact them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar problem and I ended up writing a `ParquetSink` that could be used with `WriteToFiles`. So it batches the records in memory given your configuration.
I've used this to create dynamic files in a batch process dependent on a field in the record, but I assume it would also work with a streaming pipeline, although I haven't tested it.

You can find the code in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/klesouza/84847bf6d083ac1cb91fb8a06610d760#file-beam_parquet_dynamicdestination-py)

```
class ParquetSink(fileio.FileSink):
    def __init__(self,
                file_path_prefix,
                schema,
                row_group_buffer_size=64 * 1024 * 1024,
                record_batch_size=1000,
                codec='none',
                use_deprecated_int96_timestamps=False,
                file_name_suffix='',
                num_shards=0,
                shard_name_template=None,
                mime_type='application/x-parquet'):
        self._inner_sink = beam.io.parquetio._create_parquet_sink(
            file_path_prefix,
            schema,
            codec,
            row_group_buffer_size,
            record_batch_size,
            use_deprecated_int96_timestamps,
            file_name_suffix,
            num_shards,
            shard_name_template,
            mime_type
        )
        self._codec = codec
        self._schema = schema
        self._use_deprecated_int96_timestamps = use_deprecated_int96_timestamps

    def open(self, fh):
        self._pw = pyarrow.parquet.ParquetWriter(
            fh,
            self._schema,
            compression=self._codec,
            use_deprecated_int96_timestamps=self._use_deprecated_int96_timestamps)

    def write(self, record):
        self._inner_sink.write_record(self._pw, record)

    def flush(self):
        if len(self._inner_sink._buffer[0]) > 0:
            self._inner_sink._flush_buffer()
        if self._inner_sink._record_batches_byte_size > 0:
            self._inner_sink._write_batches(self._pw)

        self._pw.close()



   def parquet_compatible_filenaming(suffix=None):
    def _inner(window, pane, shard_index, total_shards, compression, destination):
        return fileio.destination_prefix_naming(suffix )(
            window, pane, shard_index, total_shards, compression, destination).replace(":", ".")

    return _inner


def get_parquet_pipeline(pipeline_options, input, output):
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        lines = (p 
                    | 'Read' >> beam.io.ReadFromParquet(file_pattern=input)
                    | 'Transform' >> beam.Map(lambda x: { 'some_key': x['some_key'], 'raw': x})
                    | 'Write to Parquet' >> fileio.WriteToFiles(
                                                path=str(output),
                                                destination=lambda x: x["some_key"],
                                                sink=lambda x: ParquetSink(
                                                                    file_path_prefix=output,
                                                                    file_name_suffix=".parquet",
                                                                    codec="snappy",
                                                                    schema=pyarrow.schema([
                                                                        pyarrow.field("some_key", pyarrow.string()),
                                                                        pyarrow.field("raw", pyarrow.string())
                                                                    ])),
                                                    file_naming=parquet_compatible_filenaming(suffix=".parquet")
                                                )
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

The parquet format is optimized for writing data in batches. Therefore it  doesn't lend itself well to streaming, where you receive records one by one. In your example you're writing row by row in a parquet file, which is super unefficient.

I'd recommand saving your data in a format that lends itself well to appending data row by row, and then have a regular job that moves this data in batches to parquet files.

Or you can do like `apache_beam.io.parquetio._ParquetSink`. It keeps records in memory in a buffer and write them in batch every now and then. But with this you run the risk of losing the records in the buffer if your application crashes.

Comment: Thank you for your useful suggestions. I think this is the best approach, while the `apache_beam.io.FileIO.WriteFiles` is suitable for row-based file formats only and it can be easily replaced with a Partition operation, given the fact that the output files number is very limited. I will try to explore this path.